# (Rails) Identifying the starting framework for a new app on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

As a noob to Rails, I have a foundational understanding of the concepts, structure, language, etc, however I'm struggling with identifying the initial framework/steps to building a new app.  I'm not looking for code, but rather some high level steps to get started, which I haven't been able to find through search thus far. From there, I'll research and work through the actual development.  I have a base rails app built with Bootstrap and Devise, but need guidance on the structure moving forward from here.

The app I'm trying to build has an admin and user section.  The admin portal will upload CSVs filled with questions to create an engagement.  The admin will also need to be able to move questions around once uploaded, add new questions and publish so the user can select it.

The user will login and select an engagement type (based on what the Admin developed).  From there, the user will fill in answers to the questions.  The user will be able to save their work, view prior engagements and edit as needed.

Any help you can provide with the starting points would be *extremely* helpful.  I've worked through other sample applications through training courses, but again, struggling to get started with this concept.

Thank you in advance.

- PP

Comment: Can I sugest youi head over to the Pragmatic Book Store and get a copy of AWDWR, (Agile Web Development With Rails)

Comment: @jamesc Thanks for the recommendation.  I’m currently reading Michael Hartl’s Rails Tutorial book along with three Rails courses on Udemy.

Comment: Both are good resources, AWDWR takes you through building a shopping website from scratch including setup, deployment and later on very in depth explanations of the framework. It's where I started and is highly recommended. It will certainly answer this question and many more you may have

Comment: Thanks - I’ll check it out.

Comment: You are talking about project requirements. You have complex features that need to be implemented by experienced developer. If you want to do by yourself then start from basic web development courses, learn programming, database management, algorithms etc. There is no any fast process to learn these.